# FloatProperty seen as a tuple when adding hard_min or hard_max

Tags: python, scripting, properties

Below is a snippet of some addon code:

```
class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.my_operator"
    ...

    threshold = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name = "Threshold",
        description = "Threshold",
        soft_min = 0.00001,
        soft_max = 0.1,
        # hard_min = 0.00001,
        # hard_max = 10,
        step = 0.01,
        precision = 5,
        default = 0.001
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        t2 = self.threshold * self.threshold
        ...
```

As is the code runs fine, but the second I uncomment either of the `hard_m**` properties I get the following error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'`.

What am I missing here?

**info:**
Blender 2.78, OSX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at the [FloatProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatProperty) documentation you will notice there is **NO hard_min/hard_max** parameters.  Suggest using min and max instead.

As an example we'll add some undefined `grombo` parameter to a [FloatProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatProperty)

```
    threshold = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name = "Threshold",
        description = "Threshold",
        soft_min = 0.00001,
        soft_max = 0.1,
        grombo = 99,
        #hard_min = 0.0001,
        #hard_max = 10,
        step = 0.01,
        precision = 5,
        default = 0.001
    )

    def execute(self, context):

        print(self.threshold)
        t2 = self.threshold * self.threshold
        print(t2)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

and run the operator in the py console

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.my_operator()
(<built-in function FloatProperty>, {'soft_max': 0.1, 'precision': 5, 'step': 0.01, 'default': 0.001, 'grombo': 99, 'description': 'Threshold', 'soft_min': 1e-05, 'name': 'Threshold', 'attr': 'threshold'})
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/batfinger/3DModels/Tests/movebones.blend/Text.001", line 25, in execute
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

ie, if there is an undefined parameter, then the value returned is a (function, {parameters}) tuple, hence the rather cryptic error.

Comment: A *grombo* parameter? Made my day :D

Comment: Well I'll be darned! I was using the documentation from https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_1/bpy.types.FloatProperty.html, where it *does* list a `hard_min` and `hard_max` property! Thanks for the heads-up!