# Changing wrap_method does not update the parameters of shrinkwrap modifier

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, shrinkwrap

So i created myself a helper function for creating a shrinkwrap modifier and manipulating the values:

```
def add_shrinkwrap(parent, name, target,
               wrap_method: str = WrapMethod.NEAREST_VERTEX,
               wrap_mode: str = WrapMode.ON_SURFACE,
               vertex_group: str = '',
               project_limit: float = 0.0,
               subsurf_levels: int = 0,
               use_project_x: bool = False,
               use_project_y: bool = False,
               use_project_z: bool = False,
               use_negative_direction: bool = False,
               use_positive_direction: bool = True,
               cull_face: str = FaceCulling.OFF
               ):
local_mod = parent.modifiers.new(name, type='SHRINKWRAP')

local_mod.target = target
local_mod.vertex_group = vertex_group

local_mod.wrap_method = wrap_method

if local_mod.wrap_method != WrapMethod.NEAREST_VERTEX:
    local_mod.wrap_mode = wrap_mode

if local_mod.wrap_method == WrapMethod.PROJECT:
    local_mod.project_limit = project_limit,
    local_mod.subsurf_levels = subsurf_levels,
    local_mod.use_project_x = use_project_x,
    local_mod.use_project_y = use_project_y,
    local_mod.use_project_z = use_project_z,
    local_mod.use_negative_direction = use_negative_direction,
    local_mod.use_positive_direction = use_positive_direction,
    local_mod.cull_face = cull_face
```

but when actually switching the wrap_method to **PROJECT** it throws me the following error in the second if-statement:

> TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: ShrinkwrapModifier.project_limit expected a float type, not tuple

AFAICT in regards to [THIS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75073/floatproperty-seen-as-a-tuple-when-adding-hard-min-or-hard-max) question the error relates to the fact that i am trying to set a parameter which is not present / available on the modifier.
Also changing the Mode in the UI reveals different sets of parameters. [image]

So is there any way to access these additional parameters or is there a "set Dirty" function which updates the modifier?

Comment: I think it comes from wrong arguments, could you also add the line where you call this function ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment :) 
The actual call would be
`mod.add_shrinkwrap(parent=object,
name='shrinkwrap.wrist',
target=target,
wrap_method=mod.WrapMethod.PROJECT,
wrap_mode=mod.WrapMode.ON_SURFACE,
vertex_group='_body',
use_negative_direction=True,
use_positive_direction=True)`

but i am assuming this to be some sort of race condition though